# CrossDomain error in web-service

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, cross-domain

I'm using a webservice to get information from the server and got this error:

```
 Error: Request for resource at http://backoffice.dev144.com/PPIWS/B144_MAPWS.ASMX by requestor from http://maps.localhost:10000/B144/Images_v2/b144_map.swf/[[DYNAMIC]]/4 is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to http://backoffice.dev144.com/PPIWS/B144_MAPWS.ASMX halted - not permitted from http://maps.localhost:10000/B144/Images_v2/b144_map.swf
```

Of course i put crossdomain file in the main server directory that looks like this:

```
    allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/
```

Can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you try to login to a different subdomain http://backoffice.dev144.com/

If you have the crossdomain.xml on the main //www website this will not work.

You need to copy the crossdomain.xml also to the backoffice.dev144.com/crossdomain.xml